# Orientation dependent CSS

Tags: css

I want different CSS specifications if screen width is less or more than 600px.

This works fine for desktops, where the `width` returns the width of the browser window.  However, for smartphones and tablets, `device-width`, `device-heigth`, `width` and `height` are the same regardless of whether the device is in `portrait` or `landscape` orientation!!

I wanted to solve that by the following specifications

```
@media (max-device-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait), (max-device-height: 600px) and (orientation: landscape)

@media (not (max-device-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait)) and (not (max-device-height: 600px) and (orientation: landscape))
```

but this does not work.  And I still have to include specifications for the desktops.  Is that really possible to do and how?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `max-device-width` and `max-device-height` you can use `max-width` and `max-height`. This is dependent on the viewport and you automatically support mobile devices with split screen support.

```css
.my-class {
    /* styling for small */
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .my-class {
          /* styles for medium */
    }
}

@media (min-width: 92px) {
    .my-class {
          /* styles for large */
    }
}
```

Tip: Try to follow the [Mobile First](https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/) approach. For this approach you are enhance you style with more rule the larger the viewport gets.

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.

Comment: Thanks for the site link, but I see no CSS examples there.

Comment: Okay, I will add an example.